# Wireless icon seen in tray but no wireless networks are seen

Tags: wireless

Have Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS installed to an ASUS eeePC with Intel(R) Celeron(R) M Processor  900MHz, 2053MB Memory

The wireless icon is seen in the tray but no wireless networks are seen.  No issues ever seen since Ubuntu install 5 months ago.

The wireless networks of others are no longer seen.  Guidance sought... supporting information uploaded to personal online folder:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=1727C265A60F257A!409&authkey=!ABw4qMWBDZ3MGeI

Answer (score 0):

make sure the Wireless Adapter plugged in properly or turned on (if laptop)
also make sure you have the latest drivers for the deivce
moreover, you can do scan using terminal :

> iwconfig

it will tell you what are the available wifi cards, it will be something like wlan0 or wlan1
if you dont find your deivce that mean you have driver problem

> iwconfig wlan0

replace wlan0 with your device, mine is wlan0, and in the most cases it will be wlan0, unless you have plugged in multiple wifi cards

Comment: I'm sorry but the reported issue has nothing to do with an adapter.  Everything is on the board.